# In which country bills could be paid in crypto?

Tags: cryptocurrency

Is there countries in the world where crypto could used as legal tender / means of payment, e.g. where a company could pay a bill in crypto?

There are a few of news that different companies starting to accept crypto as payment. How is it organised from the legal side?

Comment: companies can accept whatever they want, they can accept oranges if that's what their customers want to pay with. *legal tender* is what they **must** accept.

Answer (score 8):

I am not aware of any country where [barter trading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barter) (exchanging wares for wares) is *not* legal as long as both parties agree. Whether you want to trade apples for oranges or Dogecoins for Ethereum makes little difference. Note that in some countries you might have to pay taxes (in form of legal tender) on barter deals under some circumstances. Check your local tax laws for details.

"Legal tender" means that in case of a dispute, courts will recognize a currency as a means for settling debts. For example, let's say we agreed to trade 20 boxes of apples for 10 boxes of oranges. You delivered the oranges, which I turned into orange juice and sold for bitcoins. But when it comes to me delivering the apples, then I have to tell you: "Well, this is awkward, but... *stuff* came up and... how should I say... uhm... I can't deliver you any apples. But I can't give you your oranges back either. So... tough luck for you I guess?!?"

We had a contract. You fulfilled your part. I did not fulfill mine. So what can you do now?

That means you can now go to a civil court and demand that I pay my debt. The court would then obligate me to reimburse you for my breach of contract in legal tender with an equivalent value of the exchanged wares instead. But they could not obligate me to procure apples or give you any of my bitcoins, because neither is "legal tender". If *you* agree to accept bitcoins and consider the debt settled, you are free to do that, and the court would close the case as "parties have made an out-of-court settlement". But the court won't make a ruling in that regard themselves. They will only sentence me to pay what their legal system considers "real" money.

But there is in fact one country in the world which recognizes a cryptocurrency (Bitcoins) as legal tender: [El Salvadore](https://en.mercopress.com/2021/06/10/bitcoin-legal-tender-in-el-salvador-first-country-ever).